# Is there a write counterpart to Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser?

Tags: .net-4.0

I need to create a new CSV file. Writing my own routine wouldn't be a big task, but is there a routine in the Base Class Library for this?

Comment: A List<String> object, but I was hoping  find an API to define column names and have all of the options that are normally available when exporting to a CSV. Is there anything if my source were a DataTable, perhaps?

Comment: I would understand your requirement if it would be a `List<List<String>>` but not with a `List<String>`. What is to be separated by comma and what by NewLine?

Comment: You are correct. It is List<List<String>>. Columns are delimited by a comma, rows by a NewLine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in the framework, the code is too simple.  Trivially done with StreamWriter.Write(), you only need to do a wee bit of lifting to properly quote a string.  It takes just a handful of lines:

```
Module CsvWriter
    Public Sub WriteCsvLine(ByVal out As System.IO.TextWriter, ByVal ParamArray Values() As Object)
        For ix As Integer = 0 To Values.Length - 1
            If ix > 0 Then out.Write(",")
            If TypeOf (Values(ix)) Is String Then
                out.Write("""" + CStr(Values(ix)).Replace("""", """""") + """")
            Else
                out.Write(Values(ix).ToString())
            End If
        Next
        out.WriteLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: if the method is called writeCsvLine, shouldn't there be a line termination character?

Comment: Missing corner cases, see Evgeny Gorb answer

Answer (score 7):

Here is the function you can use to generate a row of CSV file from string list (IEnumerable(Of String) or string array can be used as well):

```
Function CreateCSVRow(strArray As List(Of String)) As String
    Dim csvCols As New List(Of String)
    Dim csvValue As String
    Dim needQuotes As Boolean
    For i As Integer = 0 To strArray.Count() - 1
        csvValue = strArray(i)
        needQuotes = (csvValue.IndexOf(",", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) >= 0 _
                      OrElse csvValue.IndexOf("""", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) >= 0 _
                      OrElse csvValue.IndexOf(vbCrLf, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) >= 0 _
                      OrElse csvValue.IndexOf(" ", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) = 0 _
                      OrElse csvValue.IndexOf(" ", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) = csvValue.Length-1)
        csvValue = csvValue.Replace("""", """""")
        csvCols.Add(If(needQuotes, """" & csvValue & """", csvValue))
    Next
    Return String.Join(",", csvCols.ToArray())
End Function
```

Comment: Use a StringBuilder instead of a List(Of String)

Comment: @TimSchmelter For adding commas in between, `String.Join` seems like a better choice. Though `csvCols` can be a plain simple array; you know the length from the start.

Comment: added a fringe case where the [code]csvValue[/code] could start or end with a space, that would otherwise be truncated